# Duplicate Application Settings

Tags: google-app-engine

Google Cloud Platform emailed me, telling me to migrate from the Master/Slave Datastore to the High Replication Datastore (HRD).

Unfortunately, [the migration instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration#duplicating_your_application) have fallen out of date. The **Duplicate Application Settings** feature is missing.

It seems that the "Administration Console" has been renamed the "Developers Console". **Application Settings** was put under "Compute / App Engine / Settings". There are a few other things to edit (cookie, auth, logs), but no **Duplicate** option. Is there still a way to access the feature?

If not, the instructions also say:

> You could manually accomplish the same thing using other capabilities of the Administration Console if you wish,

What would that entail?

Answer (score 2):

[The old console interface](https://appengine.google.com/settings) is still accessible and contains the documented **Duplicate Application Settings** feature.

> Only the application title and access control settings are copied during this copy process.